# HP UFT 12.02: How to reach files in ALM Test Plan with Test Batch Runner

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I am trying to add test to 'Test Batch Runner'.
All the test are in ALM Test Plan with path 'Subject\UFT'.
The 'Test Batch Runner' is not able to find this tests.
Does someone had the same issue? Or maybe know how to move the test to local machine  btw. File System?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Test Batch Runner Overview**
You can use Test Batch Runner only on tests stored on the file system. You cannot use Test Batch Runner for tests stored in ALM.

*Source: UFT_UsersGuide.pdf*

You can use OTA to Download all the UFT test scripts.